# GLFW + Visual Studio 2012 - Linking Error

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012, linker-errors, glfw

I am currently trying to create a little application in Visual C++ with OpenGL.
Therefor I got myself glfw and glew for my Visual Studio 2012.
I followed a guide I found for each on how to link them to the project, but I get a bunch of errors when trying to compile:

```
error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_glfwInit" in Funktion ""public: void __thiscall OpenGL::MainLoop(void)" (?MainLoop@OpenGL@@QAEXXZ)". D:\BachelorArbeit\OpenGL_TEST\OpenGL_TEST\OpenGL_TEST\OpenGL.obj    OpenGL_TEST
```

and 6 more of those (don't think each individual error is really important at this point.

I have the glfw files in the system directories as the guides I had suggested (I read up on here allready that it's bad practice, but I basicly tried it when trying to get this error fixed).

I have added the extra library directory in the Linker-settings as well. Also tried the #pragma solution.

What I currently think is that I might possibly have the files in to many places, or yet not in the right ones with the right connection.
I'll admit, I rarely had to work with linking before so I can't claim to have experience with it.

If any additional information are required I'll most gladly add them.

PS: Sorry for the german in the error-code, I use a german Version of Visual Studio.

Comment: You've added the library directory, but it appears you haven't added the libraries themselves. You need to do that too.

Comment: Well, I followed a guide as I mentioned that said adding the library directory with the libraries inside would allow Visual Studio to find them, I'll try adding them into the Project manually

Comment: edit: either that didn't work or I put them in the wrong place(s).
Put them just about anywhere I could imagine they could fit and yet the same error.

Comment: No you don't add them to the project, you name the libraries in the library settings. IIRC it's on the input tab of the linker settings. I guess the confusion is that linkers link more than just libraries, so the input to a linker is not called 'libraries'.

Comment: hmm... if that isn't the Additional Library Directories or Additional Dependencies, I don't quite know where.
At least I can't seem to find any further options regarding libraries (might of course just have overlooked something)

Additional Dependencies is probably what you meant there, it's on the Input tab.

Comment: Additional Dependencies is correct. You put the directory in the Additional Library Directories line, and the library names (including .lib but without the path) in the Additional Dependencies line.

Comment: I have glfw3.lib;glfw3dll.lib; and a few more in there, won't work still.
leaving out the dll one (as the guide I used suggested) doesn't work either

Comment: Are you errors still about external symbols, or are they now about missing libraries.

Comment: error is still exactly the same I posted in the question above, hasn't changed at all.
It's either not finding them properly even though I put them in as you suggested, or it is having trouble from finding it automatically in other, to many, places... but to be honest, I have no idea.

Comment: Could you post a link to the gude you are following?

Comment: let me check, should still have it saved somewhere

Comment: for glew I went with the basic guide on the page (http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html), seems to have worked just fine.
with glfw, I first had this guide: http://www.hightech-journal.net/opengl-tutorial-visual-studio-mit-glfw-einrichten
It's in german, and just about adding the library directory and additional dependencies, didn't work yet.
Then I added step 3 of this: http://shawndeprey.blogspot.de/2012/02/setting-up-glfw-in-visual-studio-2010.html (plus the additional files the newer glfw version has). Only did step 3 from this, the rest I had from the guide before.

Comment: It's hard to say what you've done wrong. Since you've tried many things and it's all a bit confused I would start again. Create a new project, reinstall GLFW etc. I agree with what you have read, it's bad practice to copy these files to the VS directories. AFAIK you should be be able to include and link with them from where you installed them. Since you did have it working from the basic guide I would focus on what changed or different about the project where it's not working.

Comment: would be the second retry then, but I guess it's the best I can.
Well thing is, glew seems to work, but my project never compiled at all... it allways threw that error.

Comment: Set it back up from scratch again a few times now, still no change.
Error is still exactly the same.
Any other ideas?

Comment: Also, does a 64bit version of windows cause trouble with it?

Comment: That's an issue, not the version of Windows as such, but if your libraries are 32-bit then your program must be compiled for 32-bit, and ditto if your libraries are 64-bit then your program must also be compiled for 64-bit.

Comment: hmm... okay, what would I have to change then?

Comment: I don't know, I don't have access to a 64-bit version of Visual Studio

Comment: Okay, for the record.
I had 64bit files for glew and glfw, but for some reason my Visual Studio was set to a default of compiling for 32bit. A little google-search helped me find a way to change that and now it compiles. Now the problems I have left are code-related, but that is for another question.

Comment: Glad it's sorted. I'll try to remember the 32/64 bit issue next time someone has a linker problem (normally linker problems are easier to solve than this). The reason VS defaults to 32 bits is that they're assuming that you want to develop for users that are still running 32 bit Windows, and of course 64 bit Windows can run 32 bit code without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Although you rproblem is solved which was caused by the the 32 bit compilation and 64 bit library linkage but just for teh record, after specifying the addtional directory for the library files, you have to specify what library files should be used to link to. either you can use the options box and specify the file name or you can use the solution below

```
#pragma comment(lib, "blah_blah.lib")
```

As a good practice this should be right after your include statements, if any